# Excel Formulae Issues

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ms-office

***A formula that takes logical inputs and outputs either true or a statement if all logical inputs are true.***

Hey there I am trying to have a cell in excel display a text of either **Valid** or **Invalid** under a column marked **Status**

```
 =AND(IF(D2<TODAY(),"Invalid","Valid"),(IF(F2<TODAY(),"Invalid","Valid"),(IF(H2<TODAY(),"Invalid","Valid"))))
```

However the above formula I entered is giving me a 'value within is a wrong data type'

With the famous #Value!.

Is there anyway anyone can point out where I went wrong?

Comment: The first part of this was just having a multiple columns say either Valid or Invalid, then i thought why not have one column that will do the job of all 3, provided that I would siv through the logic that is giving me a false statement

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for AND()?? That would solve your problem immediately.

Comment: Ok checked the documentation and I guess it is asking for the the first section of the argument..

That is to say remove the [,"Invalid","Valid"] for all arugments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element inside of AND() needs to be an expression that evaluates to either TRUE or FALSE. Your formula has a single IF() statement inside of AND() that returns a text.

Guessing at what you would like to achieve, try

```
=IF(AND(D2<TODAY(),F2<TODAY(),H2<TODAY()),"Invalid","Valid")
```

in words: If D2 is before today AND F2 is before today AND H2 is before today, then return the text "Invalid", otherwise return the text "Valid"

Comment: Lol thank you.. I almost figured it out too. Thank you very much

Comment: Yea ignored the inner if but thanks Bigben for that.